# Angular 2 / Webpack - CLI parameters not working

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to pass my webpack scripts parameters from the command line

```
CLI -> NPM -> package.json -> WEBPACK
```

most of the posts I found only refer to setting the parameters in package.json

```
package.json -> WEBPACK
```

I just can't make it work

in my package.json, I first tried

```
"build": "webpack -- --test",
"build": "webpack -- test",
"build": "webpack test",
```

I end up with errors like

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'test'
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '--test'
```

- how do I make this work?
- how do I make this test value passed via the command line when I run npm?
- should I use process.env or argv to get the passed parameter?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is

CLI:

```
npm run build -- --env.something=true
```

package.json :

```
"build": "webpack"
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(env) {

  if (env.something=== 'true') {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use argv node package to pass command line argument - https://www.npmjs.com/package/argv

or

You can pass --env=test for instance through command line and then you can export a function of env which returns an instead of directly an object
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env

**sample**

Custom argumens can be passed via --env prefix, i. e. --env.compress. Than export a function from the webpack.config.js and it's called with the env parameter.

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  // ...
  if (env.compress === 'true') {
    var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
    config.plugins.push(
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: '{file}',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            regExp: /\.js$|\.html$/
        }))
  }
}
```

Comment: why the need of argv package, it appears I can use process.argv.slice( 2 )

Comment: I made it kinda work doing "npm run build -- --env=test" .... but then the env contains directly the parameter

Comment: ok --env=test does not work, it has to be --env.something=test